# Run db commands one after another in gulp

Tags: gulp

I have multiple commands to run in array which has to run once after the other. How can i run these multiple commands one after the other in a gulp task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [run-sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence).

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('first', function () {
    // Do first task and return stream.
});

gulp.task('second', function () {
    // Do second task and return stream.
});

gulp.task('run', function () {
    runSequence('first', 'second', function () {
        // Do something when finished.
    });
});
```